# C# and "&" operator used with pointer casting

Tags: c#

Why the and operator acts differently when used:

1. with un unsigned int
2. with a byte array represiting the same value when casted to (uint*)

   ```
   unsafe
   {
       fixed (byte* i = new byte[4] { 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0xFF })
       {
           uint m = 0x020304FF;

           Console.WriteLine("{0:X}",m & 0xFF000000); 

           Console.WriteLine("{0:X}",*(uint*)i & 0xFF000000); 
        }
    }
   ```

result is

```
     2000000
     ff000000
```

Comment: Note: the whole `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(foo, 16))` can be shortened to `Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", foo)`. The `Convert` class is pretty useless in general.

Comment: Those pesky little endians are running circles around you (sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a 32 bits [little-endian system](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/) (like any Intel processor, in the vast majority of today's computers), casting the address of the byte-array {02 03 04 FF} to the address of a 32 bit int will result in an int with the value 0xFF040302. Hence the result.

In other words, your assumption that it's "the same value" is not correct.

Comment: isn't supposed to be the same thing with uint m = 0x020304FF?

Comment: @anouar204 No. if you were to inspect the internal memory storage of uint m, you would find that it is the bytes `FF 04 03 02` in that order. Again, assuming a little-endian system (that is, any Intel processor)

Comment: Ok that means : because { 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0xFF } is stored as it in memory represets an int with the value FF040302

Comment: True. And there are reasons to do it like that; in many ways it's more logical that using big-endian. But I don't want to be drawn into a discussion about big vs little endian...